# Mobx not updating when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, react-table

I am using react-table with mbox and have run into a issue where my state is not updating.

I have a table like this

```
<ReactTable
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
  showPageSizeOptions={false}
  resizable={false}
  className="-striped -highlight"
  defaultPageSize={12}
  filterable={true}
/>
```

A column that has

```
{
  Header: "",
  accessor: "checkbox",
  filterable: false,
  width: 35,
  Cell: ({ original }) => {
    return (
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        className="checkbox"
        checked={employeeUiStore.selectedEmployees.indexOf(original.id) >= 0 }
        onChange={() => employeeUiStore.toggleCheckbox(original.id)}
      />
    );
  }
},
```

and a store like this

```
class EmployeeUiStore {
  @observable addMode = false;
  @observable selectedEmployees = []
  constructor(){}
  @action
  toggleCheckbox(employeeId) {
    const index = this.selectedEmployees.indexOf(employeeId);
    if(index === -1){
      this.selectedEmployees = [...this.selectedEmployees, employeeId];
    }else {
      const newSelectedEmployees = [...this.selectedEmployees];
      newSelectedEmployees.splice(index, 1);
      this.selectedEmployees = newSelectedEmployees;
    }
  }  
  @action
  toggleAddEmployee(){
      this.addMode = !this.addMode;
  }
}
export default EmployeeUiStore;
```

The weird thing is if I add something like this to my code

```
console.log(employeeUiStore.selectedEmployees.indexOf(0) >= 0)
```

Then states will update properly but when I remove this line then nothing is updated.

I see that my toggleCheckbox is being triggered and the state is being updated.

I also do have @observer on this component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not dereferencing anything when you pass the `data` array to the `ReactTable` component.

You can resolve this by either [using `slice` or `peek`](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html) on the array before you pass it to external libraries:

```
<ReactTable
  data={data.slice()}
  columns={columns}
  showPageSizeOptions={false}
  resizable={false}
  className="-striped -highlight"
  defaultPageSize={12}
  filterable={true}
/>
```

There is also no need for immutability in MobX. You can alter the array straight away:

```
class EmployeeUiStore {
  @observable addMode = false;
  @observable selectedEmployees = [];

  @action
  toggleCheckbox(employeeId) {
    const index = this.selectedEmployees.indexOf(employeeId);
    if (index === -1) {
      this.selectedEmployees.push(employeeId);
    } else {
      this.selectedEmployees.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  @action
  toggleAddEmployee(){
    this.addMode = !this.addMode;
  }
}

export default EmployeeUiStore;
```

Comment: Is peek a built in? I am getting undefined. I tried using slice like columns.slice().sort() but still not 100% working. the actually checkbox does not actually check.

Comment: @chobo2 My bad, I used `peek` on the wrong array. You should use it on the observable `data`. Yes, it's a MobX built in.

Comment: do I need to import something, I get "peek is not a function"

Comment: @chobo2 That's frustrating. `slice` works just as well. I updated the answer to that. You can also mutate your data straight away, no need for immutable techniques. I updated `toggleCheckbox` in the answer.

Comment: yea, that was left over code from when I was just using reactjs state. It works better but still not 100%. I have 3 rows in the table, it starts off ok, once I start click a few times it seems like it loses the state. Could it be because the data is actually an array made from Mobx State Tree?

Comment: @chobo2 If it stops working after the 1 click it is most likely because of the immutable React-like code. If you overwrite the observable array (`this.selectedEmployees = [ ... ]`) with a regular array, it will stop being observable.

Comment: @ Tholle  - I changed my code to what you have. It still loses state after a few clicks.